# I am using Laravel. I am using gmail to send a welcome email after the user has registered but I am not getting the email. Can someone help me

Tags: laravel

This is how I write my code.

Welcome Email Notification after user's registration

RegistrationController.php

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    //$user->notify(new WelcomeEmailNotification($user));

    Mail::send('layouts.WelcomeEmailNotification', $data, function(message)
    {
        $message->from('noreply.rewardsystem@gmail.com', 'Laravel');
        $message->to($data['email']);
    });

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: What mail driver are you using in `config/mail.php`? Gmail will only let you do this via their own SMTP servers, and only with credentials for the `noreply.rewardsystem@gmail.com` address.

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai I just follow the step to make this from google and there's no error displayed but I still do not receive the welcome email? Where else is the mistake I made

Comment: what is the mail driver you are using

Comment: smtp @ManojKiranAppathurai

Comment: can you change that to sendmail

Comment: for development I suggest to use mailtrap.io